# How can I remove part of pod file in iOS swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

[image]

How can I remove part of pod file in iOS swift project?
If i use part of this framewrok, Apple reject my App cause of True Depth APIs.

### My idea

I reserched other way in Stack Over Flow and tried long time but failed.

(1) Remove by pod file editting
Failed. Because always thease 3 items is set.

(2) Right Click + delete
Failed. Many error message is happen.

(3) project target > build Phase > Link Binary With Libraries
Failed. I dont see a file in Link Binary With Libraries.

[image]

---

I add my Progress.

I got understand about this podfiles.
There are mixed group and single.
For example, I tried pod files like these one.
- Curry rice
- Curry
- Rice

I only tried install Curry rice. I could install Curry Only.
I tried continue to build my project.

Comment: can you show your podfile

Comment: for remove any pod which you added in podfile before and installed you just open you podfile and remove that pod name from podfile and install again that will be remove. as i can see in you just need to remove pod 'VTuberKit'  from your pod and just install again from terminal

Comment: I attached my pod file. Screenshot is here.

Comment: I am wondering that there are 3 in 1. I need to use part of this pod file,.

Comment: @Paulw11: The duplicate has been auto-deleted by Community♦. I think this question should be either reopened or deleted, but I lack the iOS knowledge to tell if it's really a valid and on-topic question or not. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the framework from the `Pod File` and run `pod install` in the terminal, 
And it will remove any framework that's not in the `Pod File` or you can comment it out with `#`

```
 use_frameworks!
 #pod 'SomeLib'
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstand about this pod file. There is another way to install these 3 pod file one by one. If I install one by one I could use them One by one.

Comment: they're probably depending on each others ... and it will cause a problem separate them  but you can, edit the framework source it contains its own PodFile, remove that from it and go to folder with terminal and run pod install